# How to receive a type from Angular 12 reactive dropdown list when change fired

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

in an Angular 12 reactive form, I have a dropdown list which is hooked up to fire on the change event.
Now the data populating the D/D is of a Type rather than just a list of strings.
When it returns I cannot get the object of Type but just selectedIndex (there is something representing the OPTION element I think, when I delve into the returned event object).

template section:

```
<div>
  <label class="form-check-label">Title</label>
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="things" (change)="onChangeThing($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null">All Things</option>
    <option *ngFor="let thing of things; " [ngValue]="thing">
      {{ thing.name }} - {{ thing.anId }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

the event called:

```
  onChangeThing(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.selectedIndex);
  }
```

How can I make it pass back the selected Thing object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`:

```html
<select formControlName="things" (ngModelChange)="onChangeThing($event)">
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-72231834?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&devtoolsHeight=50)

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob, thanks for your answer. One thing - hasn't the use of ngModel and ngModelChange been deprecated for use in Angular reactive forms?